# What is the need of ToString() in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm using the below code in c sharp. But both the WriteLine statements are giving the same result 25. Then what is the need for converting Tostring in c sharp? Is there any special purpose?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sample
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 25;
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With `value` as above, `string str1 = value;` will give an error at compile-time, while `string str2 = value.ToString();` is OK. So the `ToString()` cannot just be left out in all cases. The method `Console.WriteLine` has many overloads, including one that takes in an `int`, so that explains why `ToString()` could be left out in your case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question, the purpose of `ToString()` is to provide a consistent mechanism to convert objects to strings. In your `Console.WriteLine(value);` example you are using an Overloaded version of `WriteLine` that takes an `int`, but in the general case of using an `object` the system needs a mechanism of providing a textual representation.

Comment: More specifically - the ToString call is implicit when calling Console.WriteLine or String.Format.

Comment: More precisely, `Console.WriteLine(25);` goes to an overload of `WriteLine` that takes in an `int`. It could be that this overload is going to use `ToString`, but the C# language and compiler make no assumptions about anything there. In the case `Console.WriteLine("hello" + 25);` the concatenation `+` is required by the specification to call `(25).ToString`; then another overload of `WriteLine` is used.

Comment: -1 implicit? That sounds like compiler trickery, (possibly associating it with the implicit keyword). Really this situation is provided by overloads, simple as that.

Comment: @weston I was trying to answer *What is the need of ToString() in C#?*

Comment: Ok, removed -1. But question appears to me to be "what is purpose of toString given I can apparently omit it?"

Comment: It still sounds a little like you are suggesting that if you pass an object to a function that expects a string argument or assign to a string variable, toString will be called for you.

Comment: The only time I can think of it being called implicitly is string concatenation: `""+myobject`

Comment: @weston `Console.WriteLine(new Person { Id = 42, Name = "Ahmad" });` See, also Ahmad's answer.

Comment: It's just an overload for `object` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx If you wrote your own method you would have to do the same, it's not happening because "the compiler expects a string"

Comment: i.e. `MyMethodThatTakesOneString(new Person { Id = 42, Name = "Ahmad" })` Is not going to work without my own overload taking `object`, and calling `ToString` **explicitly**.

Comment: @weston and if `object` did not have `ToString()` (because there was no such thing as `ToString()`)? How would Console.WriteLine(object) work?

Comment: I don't disagree with that. I disagree with the statement "the call is implicit (when the compiler expects a string)". The compiler has no hand in this. It's an overload explicitly calling ToString.

Answer (score 5):

You should override `ToString` in a class to give it a desired string representation. The `Console.WriteLine` method calls `ToString`, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx):

> Otherwise, the `ToString` method of value is called to produce its
>   string representation, and the resulting string is written to the
>   standard output stream.

Take this class for example:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now try to display it:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Person { Id = 42, Name = "Ahmad" });
```

The class doesn't override `ToString`, so the output is something like: `MyNamespace.Program+Person`

Now, let's override `ToString` to display a friendlier string representation:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - {1}", Id, Name);
    }
}
```

Now the `Console.WriteLine` returns `42 - Ahmad`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) of any object is supposed to return a string representation of that object. In your Code,

Int32, it returns a string correspoding to the object (value of the integer).

```
int value = 25;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Adding A bit more Information,If you decompile Your Program you can find that

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString())
```

The above line would call

```
/**Methods are from mscorlib.dll**/
    public virtual void Write(string value)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    this.Write(value.ToCharArray());
                }
            }
```

While,

> Console.WriteLine(value);

The above line would call

```
   public virtual void Write(int value)
    {
        this.Write(value.ToString(this.FormatProvider));
    }
```

If you are curious to know,how the Cast is made(ToString),then this might help you.

Answer (score 2):

As you might know that `Tostring()` Returns a string that represents the current object. You are right both lines (with and without `Tostring()`) would return same result because even if you don't use `Tostring()` there will be an implicit call to it since `Console.writeline()` prints a String representation.

Read more about [this here.](http://dotnetmagazines.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/why-do-you-always-see-tostring-method-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

.NET is calling the ToString method implicitly when you pass the object to WriteLine.

Answer (score 1):

In programming languages ToString() or its equivalent is used to represent any object textually. Or simply it can be said that it is just used to convert any object to plain string format.