# Convert object to string in C#

Tags: c#, string, object

If I have a object that looks like this:

```
Person person1 = new Person { FirstName = "name", LastName = "name2" };
```

Is it possible to turn it into a string that looks like this?

```
"name; name2"
```

Comment: Read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24719992/335858)

Comment: `string.Format("{0}; {1}", person1.FirstName, person1.LastName)`, no? FWIW: it is not a requirement to have a/use ToString to create a string from an object.. for non-trivial types, ToString is often "best for debugging" as there are usually specific business rules depending on usage.

Comment: @user2864740 I'll probably do it your way. The code does get a bit long when doing this with objects that have many properties but it seems to be the best way.